# ¿Cómo modificar el valor a un "enumerado" ya declarado?

Tags: c++

**enumerado = enun**

buenas, mi pregunta consiste si existe alguna forma de modificar el valor a un enumerado despues de que se declare.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    enum dia {lunes , martes, miercoles = -20, jueves};
    int a = miercoles;
    cout << a;

    miercoles << 7;   //segun el compilador debia de cambiar el signo de = a <<
    cout << miercoles;// mi objetivo es que miercoles sea igual a 7
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sé si con "enumerado" te refieres a lo que en el estándar C++ se llama "enumeration" (el tipo) o "enumerator" (las constantes con nombre que pueden incluirse en una enumeration) pero de todos modos la respuesta es no, no puedes modificar la cantidad ni el valor de los enumerators después de que hayan sido declarado; en particular, el estándar C++ dice:

> 7.2.2 ... The identifiers in an
>   enumerator-list are declared as constants, and can appear wherever constants are required

Los enumerators son constantes a las que se les ha dado un nombre y, debido a su naturaleza de constantes, no es posible modificar sus valores.

Y efectivamente, pueden aparecer allí donde se requiera una constante; por ejemplo:

```
enum E{cero, uno, dos, tres};
char c[tres]; // bien, el nombre "tres" es la constante 3.
```

Comment: si, me referia a *enumeration*, por algo lo intente aclarar en el principio

Comment: @bassily Sí, disculpa, ahora lo veo, fuerte y claro, grande como una casa.

Answer (score 1):

En tiempo de ejecución no se puede modificar la estructura o modificar los valores dentro de un **[enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2dzy4k6e.aspx)**.

Enumeración es un tipo cuyo valor esta restringido a un rango de valores (Enumeradores) los cuales pueden incluir varias constantes con nombre de forma explícita.

De hecho puedes verlo en tu propio programa, tendrás como salida
`-20-20` , ya que no puede ser modificado el valor de `miercoles`:

```
int main() {
    enum dia {lunes , martes, miercoles = -20, jueves};
    int a = miercoles;
    cout << a;
    miercoles << 7;   //segun el compilador debia de cambiar el signo de = a <<
    cout << miercoles;// mi objetivo es que miercoles sea igual a 7
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: consulta.¿por que al lado de *int* y *char* haz puesto "argc" y "argv"?

Comment: @bassily en algunos compiladores por default te genera esa estructura para recibir esos parámetros, lo cambie por el constructor simple main() que en este caso funciona de igual forma.

Comment: y que significan?

Comment: Hola Bassily, regularmente se reciben así (int argc, char *argv[]) , argc es el numero de argumentos pasados al programa mediante el método main() , *argv[] es un puntero que define un arreglo de strings.